# How to access the default background color of a textfield in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get the default color for a standard material textfield (a slight grey).
Is there a way to access this color with `Theme.of(context)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can by:

```
Theme.of(context).inputDecorationTheme.fillColor
```

this will get you the default theme color of the text field widget.